# Cannot launch an application in WS_MAXIMIZE using ShellExecute from Delphi Rio in Windows 10

Tags: delphi, shellexecute

I tried to run an App using ShellExecute. It ran, but not shown (I can see the instance in TaskManager).

```
    ShellExecute(0, PChar('open'), PChar(ExtractFileName(edExePath.Text)),
    PChar(theParameter), PChar(theFolder), WS_MAXIMIZE);
```

What should I do so the app will be launched in max windows size?

Comment: It works for me and `notepad`. Is there something peculiar with the application you are trying to launch? Are you using a fully-qualified path? Does it work without trying to maximize the window? What does `ShellExecute` return?

Comment: You shouldn't use `ShellExecute()` to start an executable. Use `WinExec()` or `CreateProcess()` instead.

Comment: @Olivier: Not WinExec!

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yeah I know it's deprecated but at least it works ;-)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: I used ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)); and it said The Operation Completed Successfully. (the number was 42).

Comment: @WisnuWidiarta: Does it work with `notepad.exe`?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: notepad is also hidden.... (they are there in the TaskManager)

Comment: @WisnuWidiarta `ShellExecute()` does not use `GetLastError()` to report errors. Use `ShellExecuteEx()` instead for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using [`WS_MAXIMIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles). That constant is a **w**indow **s**tyle.

You should be using [`SW_MAXIMIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea). That's a flag for the `ShowWindow` function.